# How to have 2 tabs for the same object, with different default filtering?

Tags: filters, tab

At our company, we want to create 2 tabs for the same object and call them differently. The object in question we want to use is the `Opportunity` object.

By default, we want one of the tab to only display opportunities based on a certain criteria (let's say **Open** opportunities). The second tab only needs to list **Closed** opportunities.

Is it possible to do so, keeping in mind that we want to:

- Have a different name for each tab;
- Keep core filtering features included in Salesforce

I have a feeling it's not possible natively and it requires a bit of Visualforce, but just want to make sure before going in.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This partially solved my issue:

```
<apex:enhancedlist type="Opportunity" height="730" customizable="false" rowsPerPage="25" Listid="[SOME-LIST-ID]" />
```

1. Create a Visualforce Page
2. Add an `apex:enhancedList` for the object you want
3. Create a list filter and put the `listId`
4. Create a tab + display the Visualforce page

Comment: I am already having an existing tab. How can I create a tab on VF Page rather than Object?

Comment: @SFDC_Learner  You can use any object for which you don't need a tab and override that object's tab with your above vf page to solve the purpose.

Answer (score 3):

In salesforce you can **not** make two tabs of a custom object.

Instead you can create a visualforce tab and use [`recordSetVar`](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000099OoIAI) and other native approach to show filtered record in that tab.

Sample:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts">
 <apex:dataList var="a" value="{!accounts}" type="1">
     {!a.name}
 </apex:dataList>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this could compare to a regular list view with filters, it only returns a list of names. We want to keep the filtering & ordering features.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this without visualforce by using list views, web tabs, and the `isdtp` url parameter.

1) Create a list view, and copy the url of said list view.

2) Create a web tab, and set the url to be the url of the list view.  You'll probably want to append `&isdtp=vw` to the url, so you don't double up on the standard salesforce header and sidebar.

Comment: This https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KeoeAAC includes some comments about this parameter working/not working in various versions. In your experience has it stayed working? (Personally I think SF's unwillingness to accept that URL parameters are part of their API pretty frustrating when typically there is no other reasonable way to accomplish something.)

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to your requirements only uses a single tab.  You can create a 'View' though to display.  In your Opportunity tab, you can click 'Create New View'.  You can create 2 views here.  One for all Open Opportunities, and one for all Closed.  It would give you pretty much the exact same thing you want besides the separate tab.