# Tabs and Add to Campaign for Standard / Customer Objects

Tags: custom-object, tab, campaign

Hello Stack Exchange.

Salesforce newbie here. I manage the back-end of a charity working with entrepreneurs, and I'm responsible for making basic admin changes and maintaining our Salesforce system.

We're currently making some changes to our Salesforce structure and I had a question about Record Types and Custom Objects and how they're viewed in Tabs.

My developer is currently away so I haven't been able to ask them for an answer, and I was hoping to find a solution I could implement myself. I've listed the problem below:

In our current model we have tabs relating to custom objects, which give list views of all the data there. These custom objects are separate from the standard Contacts and Organisation.

[image]

Unfortunately, on the list view of these tabs, there's no functionality to add the contacts to a Campaign as they're custom objects.

[image]

However, in a previous iteration, we had a list view for a Record Type (NEFer) which we could add to Campaigns / send email to list, like the button below for Contacts.

[image]

As I understand it, you can't have two tabs for the same object. However, previously, we had a Tab for NEFer (which we could add to campaigns from) AND a Tab for Contacts.

I'm a little confused by this, have I overlooked something obvious?  Ideally, we'd want Tabs for each Record Type (Coach, Mentor, Donor etc..)

Answer (score 0):

By default, you can't create more than one tab for the same object.

A solution to approach your requirement.

1- Creating a Visualforce
2- Create a Visualforce Tab and associate to the VF
3- Use apex:enhancedlist tag and refer the list view

Documentation: [Using Enchanted list view](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_enhancedList.htm)

[Here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29542/how-to-have-2-tabs-for-the-same-object-with-different-default-filtering) we have a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking your questions as below:

> 1. As I understand it, you can't have two tabs for the same object.
> 2. I'm a little confused by this, have I overlooked something obvious? Ideally, we'd want Tabs for each Record Type (Coach, Mentor, Donor etc..)

You are right here for #1.

For #2, Tabs are always associated to an Object. You **cannot** have Tabs for each Record Type. Record Types are logical segregation of the same object say an Internal Account vs. External Account, etc.

Now for this:

> However, previously, we had a Tab for NEFer (which we could add to campaigns from) AND a Tab for Contacts.

Add to Campaign button will add a Campaign Member to the Campaign. And that a Campaign Member can always be of type Contact, Lead or Person Account. You will always find this button on Lead, Contact and Account objects and [reports](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=campaigns_reportwizard.htm&type=5).

So if you had a Tab for NEFer, I would assume that you had a corresponding object for that. And if at all you had a Add to Campaign button available on that Tab, then either your Tab was overridden, or your one of the standard objects was renamed, or you had a custom button available there. Unless you provide more details on what exactly is your NEFer object and details around the button itself, it is difficult to say how was that button available there.

Comment: Hi Jayant,  thank you so much for your answer, it confirms what I thought.  I wish I could give more info, but the previous model we had has been replaced with new Custom Objects, none of which have the functionality to Add to Campaign.

Comment: And as I mentioned, unless there was some sort of override or customization, you won't have that button ootb.

Comment: So I've resolved this. The Contacts were Related to a Custom Object, so when you click on the Tab it takes you to a page were you can select lists of that specific Record Type. Thanks for your help!